# Quotient Rule Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How would I solve a question like this:

If $h(x)=\sqrt{4+2f(x)}$, where $f(1)=8$ and $f′(1)=2$, find $h′(1)$

I know it is solved through the quotient rule, therefore I would have to multiply them by each other using the quotient rule  $f(x)*h'(x)+f'(x)*h(x)$

But how do I actually solve this question..?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly take the derivative of $h(x)$ and then calculate $h'(1)$...

$h'(X) = \frac{2f'(x)}{2\sqrt{4+2f(x)}} = \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{4+2f(x)}}$

As we know f(1) and f'(1)...

$h'(1) = \frac{f'(1)}{\sqrt{4+2f(1)}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{4+2*8}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{20}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$

Comment: Oh alright thank you!

Comment: Okay so for this a question like this: Let r(x)=f(g(h(x))), where h(1)=3, g(3)=2, h′(1)=7, g′(3)=−2, and f′(2)=5. Find r′(1). In this question all the x's are not the same, like there is one where x=1 and for the function of g x=3